# Compensated demand function for perfect complement indifference curve

Tags: microeconomics

For example, the indifference curve for goods $A$ and $B$ is $min$. How should I express its compensated demand function if the quantity of A does not depend on its price because of the zero substitution effect?

Comment: Hi! What have you tried so far?

Comment: I understand now, A should be exactly equal to U